# SQL Server 2012 stored procedure does not return any result in JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 which has a few parameters including table type parameters as well, as SQL server 2012 does not support table type parameters i wrote another stored procedure by setting default values for this table type parameter and having only varchar as parameter for the new procedure

```
DECLARE @pTempTable TABLE(

   region varchar(max),
   country varchar(max),
   username varchar(max),
   firstname varchar(max),
   lastname varchar(max),
   accessform varchar(max),
   accessmodule varchar(max),
   adate varchar(max),
   atime varchar(max)
 )

 BEGIN

  DECLARE @pTestFromDate DATETIME = '2008/01/01', @pTestToDate      DATETIME     = '2014/12/31'

   DECLARE @pCountryIds GuidsTableType
   INSERT @pCountryIds VALUES(NULL)

   DECLARE @pRegionIds GuidsTableType
   INSERT @pRegionIds VALUES(NULL)

   DECLARE @pUserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL
   DECLARE @pModuleId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL

    insert into @pTempTable exec usp_rpt_UserAudit
   @RoleName = @pRoleName
  ,@pCountryIds=@pCountryIds
  ,@pRegionIds=@pRegionIds
  ,@pUserId=@pUserId
  ,@pModuleId=@pModuleId
  ,@pFromDate=@pTestFromDate
  ,@pToDate=@pTestToDate
  SELECT * from @pTempTable


END

GO
```

I have written a java code to execute this stored procedure, i am able to establish the connection, but the execute() method always returns false. The java code is as below

```
    String finalSql = "{ call usp_rpt_sprocexecution(?) } ";
    CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(finalSql);
    cs.setString(1, "Super Administrator");
    System.out.println(cs.execute());
    int c=0;

    while(!((cs.getMoreResults() == false) && (cs.getUpdateCount() <= 1))){
        System.out.println(c++);
        ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
```

When i execute this same stored procedure in Management Studio it returns correct result table.

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the start of the procedure. The messages like `1 row(s) affected` are being passed back, and probably being interpreted as result sets. This will suppress these messages.

Answer (score 3):

The procedure returns messages like 1 row(s) affected which is treated as a Stored Procedure output in java hence subsiding the original result.

The Simple trick was to add **SET NOCOUNT ON** at the start of the Stored Procedure so that it does not return such messages and hence returns the actual output.